# Why am I not seeing as many page fault as I expect?

Tags: linux, paging, lxc

I am trying to explore the page fault behavior of Linux.
I made an lxc container with restricting the memory to 1GB
(by adding 'lxc.cgroup.memory.limit_in_bytes = 1G' to /etc/lxc/default.conf).
Then, I ran a simple code which accesses 2GB amount of data.

```
int main() {
  char* buf = malloc(1024*1024*1024);
  char* buf2 = malloc(1024*1024*1024);
  if (buf == 0 || buf2 == 0) {
    printf("Malloc failed!\n");
    return 0;
  }
  int i,j,k;
  for (i=0; i<1024; i++)
    for (j=0; j<1024; j++)
      for (k=0; k<1024; k++)
        buf[i*1024*1024 + j*1024 + k] = i+j+k;
  for (i=0; i<1024; i++)
    for (j=0; j<1024; j++)
      for (k=0; k<1024; k++)
        buf2[i*1024*1024 + j*1024 + k] = i+j+k;
  free(buf);
  free(buf2);
  while(1);
  return 0;
}
```

The code is compiled with -O0 and ran inside the container.
When the program reaches the while(1);, I check how many page fault it experienced with

```
ps -eo maj_flt,cmd | grep a.out
```

Where a.out is the compiled executable.
Sometimes I get 200~300 page faults; however, sometimes I only see 10~20 page faults.
Because memory is only 1G, I think at least always 1G/4K = 256K page fault should be happening.
Why am I only seeing 10~20 page fault sometimes? I confirmed my Linux uses 4K pages as default.

I am new to Linux. Any insights will be very helpful! Thank you.

Comment: I am not a Linux internals expert, but I'm thinking that perhaps the O/S is clever enough to remap several pages in response to a single page fault. How does it change if you do random access? Incidentally, what happens when you assign the value 3069 to a char?

Comment: I tried randomizing the access. Now I get much more faults (~2K), but much less than 256K which I think should occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem.

1. A major problem with my code was that on first write to the malloc'ed page, page fault does not occur because Linux does not have to read an empty page from the disk. I changed the code so that it runs the looping part of the code twice.
2. Also, I disabled Linux readahead (by echo "0" >> /proc/sys/vm/page-cluster)

With the two changes, I was able to see roughly 2G / 4K = 524,288 page faults
(precisely 524,304).